# deep chaning via $parent calls in angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a code where i am accessing the controller via a deep `$parent` inheritance, like below:

```
$scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.myMethod();
```

Two questions:

1. Does doing this way, bring any downside to performance? Is it a wrong practice to do in such a way or a performance bottle-neck?
2. Instead of deep inheritance, is it better to go with `$emit/$broadcast`

Comment: It's not so much a performance issue as it is tightly coupling that code to that structure which becomes a maintenance issue. Events and injection are better like Chris' answer below

Comment: Is every scope up the chain actually isolated? There should be some inheritance in play here...

Comment: Are your scopes isolate? If not, they prototypically inherit `$parent`, and you should be able to do `$scope.myMethod()`.

Answer (score 0):

`$emit/$broadcast` are my preferred ways, because they are more declarative/explicit and avoid any digest operations and unneeded computation.

You can also simply use and inject a Service into both controllers, and they can both share and use its methods/values.

Performance is best tested in Chrome Developer Tools.